# Duplicate a Worksheet_Change VBA function to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that I've pieced together from a couple examples. I got it to work on one sheet but now I would like to duplicate that same code to a different sheet in the same workbook. However, I can't figure out what is the correct combinations of variables that I need to rename to get it to work. And a couple of times I have managed to somehow screw up my code on the original sheet in the process.

Here is the code. It's based on a couple of samples that are out on the web in several spots but I modified it a bit to change one cell to today's date and a different cell to the Application.Username.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but would appreciate assistance.

(The code is currently on Sheet2 and I would like to also use the same exact code on Sheet3 - the data on both sheets is identical format wise.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange As Range
Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

'Your data table range
Set myTableRange = Range("K:K")

'Check if the changed cell is in the data tabe or not.
If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Stop events from running
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Column for the date/time
Set myDateTimeRange = Range("J" & Target.Row)
'Column for last updated date/time
Set myUpdatedRange = Range("J" & Target.Row)

'Determine if the input date/time should change
If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then

    myDateTimeRange.Value = Now

End If

'Update the updated date/time value
myUpdatedRange.Value = Now

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then
With Target(1, -1)
.Value = Application.UserName
.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End If

'Turn events back on
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to rename any variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to extract your code to a separate method and call it from respective event handlers `Worksheet_Change`. This way, you can prevent unnecessary duplication from your codebase as well as you have ability to easily call this method `UpdateDates` from other sheets if required.

Here is an example:

```
' Code in Sheet2 module
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    UpdateDates Target
End Sub

' Code in Sheet3 module
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    UpdateDates Target
End Sub

' Code in any standard module
Public Sub UpdateDates(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Your code goes here.
End Sub
```